# Magento Multi-Website Problems

Tags: multistore, magento2.3.4, multi-website

I'm having some trouble configuring a multi-site setup for my employer's website.

Our server provider has setup two seperate domains running off the same server and webroot.

I have completed all the requisite steps in the Magento admin panel.

However, when I proceeded to editing the index.php and htaccess files I ran into some issues.

**For example:**

My index.php currently looks like this:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
case 'domain2.com.au':
case 'www.domain2.com.au':
$mageRunCode = 'domain2';
$mageRunType = 'website';
break;
}
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $mageRunCode;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $mageRunType;
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

The 2nd domain no longer redirects to the main website. However, it presents the following error in the Exception log:

> [2021-04-27 03:18:13] main.CRITICAL: No such entity.
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No
> such entity. at
> /var/www/html/cyclemotion.com.au/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/GroupRepository.php:70)"}
> []

I can't seem to find much online about this specific issue.

So I would really appreciate the help if anyone has experienced something similar. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**please try to Magneto root second domains name folder link "domain2" in index.php file create and this code try to.Please check link**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dUrezPuIW7upn_4CUZp46KxmPj6PUOFIEfWiiJo3oMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. It returned a HTTP 500 error.